# Swap out blocks based on domain name extension

Tags: blocks, domain-access

We have a European site that is the same exact site for three different domain names. So `www.mysite.eu`, `www.mysite.ie` and `www.mysite.ch` all go to the same site. However, we would like to make very small subtle changes based on which domain extension they come from. Really, I just need to swap out a couple blocks based on the domain.

I know there is the `Domain Access` module, which we actually use on another site, but I really didn't want to have the huge overhead and configuration and headache of everything that comes with the Domain Access module, just to swap out a couple blocks and that's it. The rest of the site in it's entirety will be exactly the same for all three domains.

I have put a hack in place using JavaScript right now, but it's not the most elegant solution. I was wondering if there is something else I could try besides Domain Access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're still using D7 (there's no D8 port at the time of writing this), you could use [Context Domain](https://www.drupal.org/project/context_domain) in conjunction with the [Context](https://www.drupal.org/project/context) module, or port the D7 version to D8. There's also option of creating a [`hook_block_access`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21block%21block.api.php/function/hook_block_access/8.2.x) invocation to control display on a `view` operation.